# How to extract the [Documentation] text from Robot framework test case

Tags: api, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I am trying to extract the content of the **[Documentation]** section as a string for comparision with other part in a **Python script**.
I was told to use **Robot framework API** https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
to extract but I have no idea how.

However, I am required to work with version 3.1.2

**Example:**

```
*** Test Cases ***
ATC Verify that Sensor Battery can enable and disable manufacturing mode
    [Documentation]    E1: This is the description of the test 1
    ...                E2: This is the description of the test 2
    [Tags]    E1    TRACE{Trace_of_E1}
    ...       E2    TRACE{Trace_of_E2}
```

**Extract the string as**

E1: This is the description of the test 1

E2: This is the description of the test 2

Comment: Are you wanting to do this from within a robot test, or from a python script?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the missing informmation.
I am trying to do this from a python script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these [examples](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.api.html). I did something similar to generate testplans descritio. I tried to adapt my code to your requirements and this could maybe work for you.

```
import os
import re
from robot.api.parsing import (
    get_model, get_tokens, Documentation, EmptyLine, KeywordCall,
    ModelVisitor, Token
)

class RobotParser(ModelVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        # Create object with remarkup_text to store formated documentation
        self.text = ''


    def get_text(self):
        return self.text

    def visit_TestCase(self, node):
        # The matched `TestCase` node is a block with `header` and
        # `body` attributes. `header` is a statement with familiar
        # `get_token` and `get_value` methods for getting certain
        # tokens or their value.
        


        for keyword in node.body:
            # skip empty lines
            if keyword.get_value(Token.DOCUMENTATION) == None:
                continue
            self.text += keyword.get_value(Token.ARGUMENT)

    def visit_Documentation(self,node):
        # The matched "Documentation" node with value
        self.remarkup_text += node.value + self.new_line 

    def visit_File(self, node):
        # Call `generic_visit` to visit also child nodes.       
        return self.generic_visit(node)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "../tests"
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if re.match(".*\.robot", filename):
            model = get_model(os.path.join(path, filename))
            robot_parser = RobotParser()
            robot_parser.visit(model)
            text=robot_parser._text()
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
But do you know how I can do this task without the parse module?
I need to work with Robot framework version 3.1.2

Comment: Sorry I am afraid, that this is as far as i can take you.

Answer (score 1):

The code marked as best answer didn't quite work for me and has a lot of redundancy but it inspired me enough to get into the parsing and write it in a much readable and efficient way that actually works as is. You just have to have your own way of generating & iterating through filesystem where you call the `get_robot_metadata(filepath)` function.

```
from robot.api.parsing import (get_model, ModelVisitor, Token)

class RobotParser(ModelVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.testcases = {}

    def visit_TestCase(self, node):
        testcasename = (node.header.name)
        self.testcases[testcasename] = {}
        for section in node.body:
            if section.get_value(Token.DOCUMENTATION) != None:
                documentation = section.value
                self.testcases[testcasename]['Documentation'] = documentation
            elif section.get_value(Token.TAGS) != None:
                tags = section.values
                self.testcases[testcasename]['Tags'] = tags

    def get_testcases(self):
        return self.testcases


def get_robot_metadata(filepath):
    if filepath.endswith('.robot'):
        robot_parser = RobotParser()
        model = get_model(filepath)
        robot_parser.visit(model)
        metadata = robot_parser.get_testcases()
        return metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will be able to extract the **[Documentation]** section from the **testcase**:

```
def documentation_extractor(testcase):
    documentation = []
        for setting in testcase.settings:
            if len(setting) > 2 and setting[1].lower() == "[documentation]":
                for doc in setting[2:]:
                    if doc.startswith("#"):
                        # the start of a comment, so skip rest of the line
                        break
                    documentation.append(doc)
                break
        return "\n".join(documentation)
```